# How to configure AWS image resize on fly in create lambda step?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, aws-lambda

So I've read the document: https://aws.amazon.com/tw/blogs/compute/resize-images-on-the-fly-with-amazon-s3-aws-lambda-and-amazon-api-gateway/

In the step To **create the Lambda function**
 1. In the Lambda console, choose Create a Lambda function, Blank Function.

I go to AWS Lambda page, it asks me to choose a blueprint to create one, anyone knows which one I should choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're creating a blank function, In the select blueprint step, you would need to Click on the option Author from scratch. This is a button on the top right corner of the panel.

Comment: What about step 2. To select an integration, choose the dotted square and choose API Gateway.

Comment: Once you're done creating a function, You need to go to that function and click on Triggers. You will find the dotted square there. You can then select and associate API Gateway from there.